# Why is the s3.PutObject not called in this snippet

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, error-handling

This node script when ran does not execute the upload, but simply goes straight to the thrown error.  Any ideas why?

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const fs = require('fs')
const s3 = new AWS.S3()

const filePathName="/tmp/readme.txt"
var numberOfErrors=1

fs.readFile(filePathName, (err,data) => {
    const fileDate = new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()
    const bucket = 'test-bucket';

    console.log('Preparing file...')

    var fileData = new Buffer.from(data);

    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: `readme.txt`,
        ContentType: 'text/html',
        Body: fileData
    }
    
    if (numberOfErrors > 0) { 
        s3.putObject(params, (err) => {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            console.log("File uploaded to S3 " + bucket)                                     
        })           
        throw new Error('There were errors') 
    } else {
        s3.putObject(params, (err) => {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            console.log("File uploaded to S3 " + bucket)                                     
        })
        console.log('There were no errors')
    }    

})
```

Output is as follows

```js
Preparing file...
sample_test.js:28
        throw new Error('There were errors') 
        ^

Error: There were errors
    at sample_test.js:28:15
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)

Node.js v17.4.0
```

if I comment out the line where I throw the error it uploads successfully.  Any help much appreciated thanks.

Comment: You're defining `numberOfErrors` as 1, and in your if check, checking if it's > 0. Which it always will be, since you're not setting it anywhere else.

Comment: Hey Matthew thanks but I hacked this together from the full script to remove all the company specific info, so its a bit odd, but yes it will always hit the first branch of the if, the problem though is that it doesn't execute the line before the throw, the s3.putObject

Comment: I think that the `s3.putObject` is likely executing asynchronously. So it will attempt to fire that function, then immediately proceed to throw the error while the `putObject` function is executing.